# Полимофизм для оператора "<<"

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, полиморфизм

```
#include <iostream>

class A {};
class B : public A {};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const A* a) {
    return out << "A";
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const B* B) {
    return out << "B";
}

int main() {
    A* arr[2];
    arr[0] = new A();
    arr[1] = new B();

    std::cout << arr[0] << arr[1];
}
```

Вот пример программы, которая выводит `AA`, как мне уточнить ***без явного*** каста к `B`(типо `B*(arr[1])`), что оператор << должен принимать `B` во втором случае?

Comment: А зачем? Может, лучше пусть ваш оператор  `<<`для `A` **использует** внутри виртуальную функцию? Тем более что в вашем варианте ничего виртуального нет, и нет в результате полиморфизма.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А зачем? Может, лучше пусть ваш оператор `<<` для `A` использует внутри виртуальную функцию? Тем более что в вашем варианте ничего виртуального нет, и в результате нет и полиморфизма.

Вот такое решение вас не устроит?

```
class A {
public:
    virtual string name() const { return "A"; }
};
class B : public A {
public:
    string name() const override { return "B"; }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const A& a) {
    return out << a.name();
}

int main() {
    A* arr[2];
    arr[0] = new A();
    arr[1] = new B();

    std::cout << *arr[0] << *arr[1];
}
```

Comment: Да, пожалуй и правда мне в данном случае поможет этот вариант, спасибо.

Comment: Ну, тогда жмите на птичку слева от ответа...

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы говорить о каком-то полиморфизме - нужны виртуальные функции. В вашем примере их вовсе нет. А есть всего лишь две перегруженные функции `operator<<`, отличающиеся типом последнего параметра. Какая из перегруженных функций будет вызвана определяется статическими типами переменных, передаваемых в функцию. Что `arr[0]`, что `arr[1]` имеют статический тип `A*`, а значит будет вызвана первая перегрузка в обоих случаях.

```
std::cout << arr[0] << arr[1];
// Т.е. вот здесь   ^^   нет ничего такого, что сказало бы компилятору - бери динамический тип!
```

Кстати, замечу, что при перегрузке операторов обычно используются ссылки, а не указатели. Собственно, ссылки в языке и появились, чтобы можно было красиво сделать перегрузку операторов.

Другой момент в том, что `operator<<` по смыслу первым аргументом должен принимать поток вывода, а для виртуальных функций первым аргументом всегда будет объект `this`, для которого реализуется эта виртуальная диспетчеризация. Ну а вообще, можно [вот так извратиться](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7GyQ1Lont4QfPcYl) (не делайте так!):

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    virtual std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o) { o << "A"; return o; }
};

struct B : A {
    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o) override { o << "B"; return o; }
};

int main()
{  
    A* arr[2] = {new A, new B};

    *arr[0] << std::cout;
    *arr[1] << std::cout;
}
```

Вывод:

```
AB
```

P.S. Адекватная реализация вашей задачи уже представлена в ответе Harry.